# My custom message Request validator not work Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, request

I use the Request validation but I don't get message from request. Look my code and see my mistake. Only important is store function which work good if all fields is fullfiled but if any field not filled i don't get my custom message from request. For not filled field I don't give error just laravel home page.

This is my request file

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;

class CarRequest extends FormRequest
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'car_type' => 'required',
            'mark' => 'required',
            'model' => 'required',
            'fuel' => 'required',
            'circuit' => 'required',
            'chassis' => 'required|numeric',
            'bill_type' => 'required',
            'first_registration' => 'required|date',
            'km' => 'required|numeric',
            'structure' => 'required',
            'motor_vehicle_check' => 'required|boolean',
            'warranty' => 'required|boolean',
            'year' => 'required|date',
            'import_vehicle' => 'required|boolean',
            'know_damage' => 'required',
            'car_accessories' => 'required',
            'email' => 'required|email'
        ];
    }

    public function messages()
    {
        return [
            'car_type.required' => 'A car_type is required',
            'mark.required'  => 'A mark is required',
            'model.required' => 'A model is required',
            'fuel.required' => 'A fuel is required',
            'circuit.required' => 'A circuit is required',
            'chassis.required' => 'A chassis is required',
            'bill_type.required' => 'A bill_type is required',
            'first_registration.required' => 'A first_registration is required',
            'km.required' => 'A km is required',
            'structure.required' => 'A structure is required',
            'motor_vehicle_check.required' => 'A motor_vehicle_check is required',
            'warranty.required' => 'A warranty is required',
            'year.required' => 'A year is required',
            'import_vehicle.required' => 'A import_vehicle is required',
            'know_damage.required' => 'A know_damage is required',
            'car_accessories.required' => 'A car_accessories is required',
            'email.required' => 'A email is required'
        ];
    }
}
```

And this is my controller code

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Car;
use App\CarImages;
use App\Http\Requests\CarRequest;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Carbon\Carbon;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Config;



class CarController extends Controller
{


    public function index()
    {
        $cars = Car::with(['images'])
            ->orderByDesc('car.created')
            ->get();

        return response()->json($cars, 200);
    }


    public function search($name){
        $cars = Car::where('mark', '=' , $name)->get();
        return $this->response($cars);
    }


    public function create()
    {
        //
    }


    public function show($id)
    {
        $car = School::with(['images'])->find($id);
        if (!$car) {
            return response()->json(['message' => 'No Car found'], 404);
        }
        return response()->json($car, 200);
    }


    public function store(CarRequest $request)
    {
            $car = Car::create([
                'car_type' => $request->input('car_type'),
                'mark' => $request->input('mark'),
                'model' => $request->input('model'),
                'fuel' => $request->input('fuel'),
                'circuit' => $request->input('circuit'),
                'chassis' => $request->input('chassis'),
                'bill_type' => $request->input('bill_type'),
                'first_registration' => $request->input('first_registration'),
                'km' => $request->input('km'),
                'structure' => $request->input('structure'),
                'motor_vehicle_check' => $request->input('motor_vehicle_check'),
                'warranty' => $request->input('warranty'),
                'year' => $request->input('year'),
                'import_vehicle' => $request->input('import_vehicle'),
                'know_damage' => $request->input('know_damage'),
                'car_accessories' => $request->input('car_accessories'),
                'email' => $request->input('email')
            ]);

            return response()->json([
                'message' => 'Your car has been successfully added',
                'car' => $car
            ],201);
        }


    public function destroy($id)
    {
        $car = Car::destroy($id);
        return response()->json($id);
    }
}
```

Comment: When you do your request, are you passing the header: `Accept: application/json`?

Comment: For testing I using postman. application/json is already set, I think...?

Comment: No is not by default, if I'm not wrong. Add it an try again.

Comment: Ahhhh that is very true. You save me. This question is already finished. Thank you.

Comment: Glad to help. I'll add it as an answer so we can close this one. Have a good day.

Comment: One more question. If I want set in my custom message example km must be numberic , how do that in messages function? This question is little  stupid but ....You are very fast solve my first question .. :)

Comment: I've updated my answer.

Comment: Btw mate, there isn't a silly question. No one is born with knowledge. Just try and look for an answer whenever you need it. I knew this because I've spend a couple of hours trying to figure it out why my code isn't working lol. To improve yourself with Laravel, I suggest you to look at the documentation. Is very user-friendly (not like other Frameworks).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I use the Request validation but I don't get message from request.

When expecting a json response, don't forget to add this header when making your requests (client side):

```php
   Accept: Application/json // <--
```

---

> If I want set in my custom message example km must be numberic , how do that in messages function?

You need to specify your message for every rule like this. Let's do it for the `km` validation:

**MyCustomRequest.php**

```php
public function rules()
{
    return [
     // ...
     // 'first_registration' => 'required|date',
        'km' => 'required|numeric',  // <---
     // 'structure' => 'required',
     // ...
    ];
}
```

Given that `km` has two validations, just add one element more in the `messages()` function specifying the rule you want to modify:

**MyCustomRequest.php**

```php
public function messages()
{
    return [
        // ...
        'km.required' => 'A km is required',
        'km.numeric' => 'The km needs to be numeric dude!', // <---
        // ...
    ];
}
```

Regarding this last subject, check [the documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/validation#working-with-error-messages).

Comment: Where do you add that in Laravel? How does this solve the problem?

Comment: @cale_b you don't add it in Laravel, you added when making your request from your front-end. If you are using PHP for your front-end you can do it with Guzzle [check this](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/request-options.html#headers). In case you are using JS, you can do it with Axios.

Comment: I wasn't asking for me :) - I'm asking for all of the future visitors that come see this, and wonder "Where do I add this?".  Just a suggestion for improving your answer.

Answer (score -1):

As I see you have done all things correctly. The only you missed  is a little one in your store() method :

```
$validator = $request->validated();
```

right at beginning of the method's body